# Prove that Group Ring RG is not a Division Ring for R commutative and G a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do I prove that a group ring RG is not a division ring, assuming that R is commutative and G=(g_1,g_2,...g_n) finite?

I understand that I need to show there exists some element of RG that is not a unit. But how do I find such element? Would the element g_1+g_2+g_3+....+g_n work?

Comment: You need to assume $G$ is non-trivial for this.

Comment: Yes, R, G are both nontrivial, but how do I find a non-invertible element?

Comment: Indeed if $G$ has any torsion element $g$ then $g^n=e$ means $g-e$ is a zero divisor.

Comment: This is very similar to a question that was deleted yesterday.  If that was in fact you, wee should remind you that reposting deleted questions will eventually get you into trouble with restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ and $R$ be nontrivial.

Let $\alpha = \sum_{g\in G}g$. We claim that $\alpha$ is not a unit in $RG$. To see this, suppose that $x = \sum_{h\in G}r_h h$ is any element of $RG$. We will show that $\alpha x\neq 1$. We have
$$
\alpha x = \sum_{g,h \in G}r_h\cdot gh = \sum_{s\in G}\Big[(\sum_{h\in G}r_h)\cdot s\Big],
$$
where the second equality makes the substitution $s = gh$. We see that each element of $G$ has the same coefficient, namely $\sum_h r_h$, in the expansion of $\alpha x$. However, $1$ has different coefficients for the identity and non-identity elements, so we cannot have $\alpha x = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $|G| > 1$ (with identity element $e$) and $R \neq \{0\}$. Consider the map

$$RG \to R, \ \ \ \ \sum_{g \in G} a_g g \mapsto \sum_{g \in G} a_g.$$

It is a ring homomorphism. Its kernel contains all elements of the form $e-g$ for $g \in G$. The kernel is a two-sided ideal in $RG$, and the map is non-trivial (because $G$ and $R$ are non-trivial). Hence $RG$ cannot be a division ring, since a divison algebra only contains the trivial two-sided ideals.

Comment: I believe you meant $\displaystyle\sum_{g\in G} a_g$, not $\displaystyle\sum_{g\in G} g$.

Comment: Oops, yes. Thanks, fixed.